# Rails: Follow/Following Relationship Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

I have a user model that can create relationships to have followers and follow others and everything I learned from the rails tutorial worked great. One thing is that I am trying to take it to the next step by adding the option of being able to see other peoples followers and be able to have the follow/following button option. Apparently the code that is in place, places everything where it should be (the followers small profile, buttons, etc.) but when I click on the button it only follows myself or defollows myself not the specific person that I choose to follow, how can I fix this? Any help is much appreciated!

This is the code for the following and followers page:

```
<div id='ContentContainer'>
<div class='ContentLeft'>
<% if @users.any? %>
<%= render @users %>
<%= will_paginate @users %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

That leads to render the user template which includes this

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
<div id="follow_form_small">
<% if current_user.followed_users?(@user) %>
<%= render 'unfollow_small' %>
<% else %>
<%= render 'follow_small' %>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And then the follow and unfollow forms respectively

```
<%= form_for current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id),
          remote: true do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", :class => 'FollowButton_small' %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user),
         html: { method: :delete },
         remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", :class => 'UnFollowButton_small' %>
<% end %>
```

**Relationship Controller**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**Relationship Model**

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true
end
```

**User Model** This was also added onto it

```
def following?(other_user)
  relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
end

def followed_users?(other_user)
  relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
end

def follow!(other_user)
  relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
end

def unfollow!(other_user)
  relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
end
```

**Follow Form**

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
<div id="follow_form_small">
<% if current_user.followed_users?(@user) %>
<%= render 'unfollow_small' %>
<% else %>
<%= render 'follow_small' %>
<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**Current User**

```
private

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

**New Edits**

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"

  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true

  validate :not_following_himself

  def not_following_himself 
    errors.add :followed_id,
     if followed_id == follower_id
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you show you you relationships controller's create method. may be there is some bug.

Comment: everything looks file put debugger in create method and see what is in   params.

Comment: @Naveed Forgot to add this, can you take a look at this, cause this might be affecting it -Edit- It actually seems I added it there but the thing is if you take a look at the last edit, if wasn't to remove the <% unless current_user?(@user) %> the buttons won't show at all, if I remove it, they show but I receive this problem.

Comment: is current_user?  is your own helper ? don't think if devise provide this.and this is fine of course you will not want to follow yourself.you remove this check and follow button displayed then if you click on follow button you will follow yourself.@bdon idea was good add validation in relationship model user should not follow himself.

Comment: are you not using Devise ? if yer don't override devise helper!. and i was excepting source of "current_user?" not "current_user"

Comment: I am currently not using Devise and here it is for current_user?     def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

Answer (score 1):

issue is with `current_user?` method. it probably returning true always and in list of users follow button is get displayed with all users(including yours entry),so by clicking on follow you can follow yourself.

Comment: Yes current_user is a helper method, hmmm so how can I prevent this from following myself and only follow others?

Comment: You can add validation in relationship model to ensure user can't follow himself.  validate :not_following_himself,                          def not_following_himself                                                     errors.add :followed_id,'You can't follow yourself' if followed_id == follower_id

Comment: That's abit confusing, I'll post as much as I got from your statement above, editted

Comment: errors.add :followed_id,"Your can't follow yourself" if followed_id == follower_id#at least this validation will not allow user to follow himself. now you can add see what is coming in params by putting debugger or simply use "puts params.inspect"  then see your console. try debugging issue, test what id output of current_user.im not sure where you are adding cookie, if there is no cookie you  are comparing nil with User,that will return false always and you same story. follow button shown for all user

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's enough code here to determine exactly what the problem is. You should provide the controller actions as well.

Here are some steps you can take to debug it:

1. The controller action for relationship/create should be using params[:followed_id] and current_user.id.
2. Add a validation to the Relationship that says followed_id != follower_id and that both IDs are present.
3. Look at the generated HTML on the "Follow" form and make sure that the value of the hidden field for followed_id is correct. The ID should be different than the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

I found my code is 95% the same as yours. however I don't use form_for, I use link_to instead:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :relationships, :only => [:create, :destroy]
```

**in my view:**

```
<%= link_to "Follow", relationships_path(:id => @user.id), :method => :post, :remote => 'true', :class => "FollowButton_small"%>
```

**relationships_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @followed = User.find(params[:id])
  current_user.follow!(@followed)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { @user = @followed}
  end
end
```

**in user.rb**

```
def follow!(followed)
  relationships.create!(:followed_id => followed.id)
end
```

hope my code helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I am using validate for follower, now, I create method for follower

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: User.name 
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: User.name 

  validate :follower, on: :create
  validate :followed, on: :create

  def follower
    errors.add :follower,
    unless current_user.follow @user
  end

  def followed
    errors.add :followed,
    unless current_user.unfollow @user
  end
end
```

My code is true?